# Finding number of words in a file in python

Tags: python

I'm new to python and attempting to do an exercise where I open a txt file and then read the contents of it (probably straight forward for most but I will admit I am struggling a bit).

I opened my file and used .read() to read the file. I then proceeded to remove the file of any punctation. 
Next I created a for loop. In this loop I began my using .split() and adding to an expression:
words = words + len(characters) 
words being previously defined as 0 outside the loop and characters being what was split at the beginning of the loop. 
Very long story short, the problem that I'm having now is that instead of adding the entire word to my counter, each individual character is being added. Anything I can do to fix that in my for loop?

```
my_document = open("book.txt")
readTheDocument = my_document.read
comma = readTheDocument.replace(",", "")
period = comma.replace(".", "")
stripDocument = period.strip()

numberOfWords = 0 

for line in my_document:
splitDocument = line.split()
numberOfWords = numberOfWords + len(splitDocument)


print(numberOfWords)
```

Comment: Could you please post the relevant code? It is very hard to help when the problem could be literally anywhere.

Comment: I'm not sure if this a direct copy of your code but there are a couple of syntax errors with the code you've posted. You need to indent in the lines after `for line in my_document:` and you have `Period` on your 4th line but then use `period` on the 5th line (Python is case sensitive)

Comment: I had to retype my code (everything is properly indented on my script and I have no syntax errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just open the file and split to get the count of words.

```
file=open("path/to/file/name.txt","r+")
count=0
for word in file.read().split():
    count = count + 1
print(count)
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I think I was making the mistake (one of many probably) of getting the length of each string, hence why I was getting character count.

Answer (score 3):

A more Pythonic way is to use `with`:

```
with open("book.txt") as infile:
    count = len(infile.read().split())
```

You've got to understand that by using `.split()` you are not really getting real grammatical words. You are getting word-like fragments. If you want proper words, use module `nltk`:

```
import nltk
with open("book.txt") as infile:
    count = len(nltk.word_tokenize(infile.read()))
```

Comment: agreed. This should be the accepted answer. To go further, we should strip punctuations as well.

Comment: @amanb Stripping punctuation is actually not so trivial because some words include punctuation (dashes, apostrophes). It boils down to the definition of a "word."

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Things like while loops haven’t yet been covered in the course I’m taking but nonetheless it is helpful info for the future

Comment: There are no while loops in this example.

Comment: Oops meant to write with (and subsequently as)